# CSS LESS class inheritance

Tags: html, css, less

Here is a css description of properties for my #myform1 .btn1 class:

```
#myform1 .btn1
{
...
}

#myform1 .btn1:hover
{
...
}
#myform1 .btn1.active
{
...
}
#myform1 .btn1.disabled
{
...
}
```

Is it possible to add absolutely the same properties for my #myform2 .btn2 class using LESS (any way is OK) without writing

```
#myform1 .btn1 ,#myform2 .btn2
{
...
}

#myform1 .btn1:hover, #myform2 .btn2:hover
{
...
}
#myform1 .btn1.active, #myform2 .btn2.active
{
...
}
#myform1 .btn1.disabled, #myform2 .btn2.disabled
{
...
}
```

Is it possible?

**Added:**

**Is it possible to use LESS in some kind of this way:**

```
@btn-superstyle
{
...
}

@btn-superstyle:hover
{
...
}
@btn-superstyle.active
{
...
}
@btn-superstyle.disabled
{
...
}

#myform1 .btn1,     #myform2 .btn2
{
 @btn-superstyle; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this less:

```
#myform1 .btn1, #myform2 .btn2 {
  /* here common styles */    

  &:hover {
    ...
  }

  &:active {
    ...
  }
}
```

For example this less:

```
#myform1 .btn1, #myform2 .btn2 {
  color: green;  

  &:hover {
    color: blue;
  }

  &:active {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

provides this css:

```
#myform1 .btn1,
#myform2 .btn2 {
  color: green;
}
#myform1 .btn1:hover,
#myform2 .btn2:hover {
  color: blue;
}
#myform1 .btn1:active,
#myform2 .btn2:active {
  color: red;
}
```

Also I recomend this resource to play with less online and look at the compiled css: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler

Comment: +1 for the answer. BUT why would you do this? You are saving only a few lines of CSS. Hours were spent to find this solution. Devs without knowledge/understanding of LESS cannot maintain this code. You are depending on LESS and JS when you don't NEED to. The only upside to using this that I can find is "saves 4 lines of code".

Comment: Flem, once I want to change the color of that buttons, I need to update the only one line of css code. Afterwards, I'm sure I changed it at all buttons. I don't need to check if I changed hover, active etc as well at another part of the file and I made any typos.